# Executing Django's sqlsequencereset code from within python

Tags: django, python-2.7

Django's [sqlsequencereset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset) command returns the SQL commands needed to reset sequences in the database.

Other similar management commands automatically execute the SQL by default (and only print out the output if you specify the --dry-run option).

From the command line you can execute the returned commands with:

```
python manage.py sqlsequencereset app1_name app2_name | python manage.py dbshell
```

But... Is there a way to directly execute the returned code from `sqlsequencereset` from inside python?

Answer (score 13):

You can execute the SQL query generated by `sqlsequencereset` from within python in this way (*using the default database*):

```
from django.core.management.color import no_style
from django.db import connection

from myapps.models import MyModel1, MyModel2


sequence_sql = connection.ops.sequence_reset_sql(no_style(), [MyModel1, MyModel2])
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    for sql in sequence_sql:
        cursor.execute(sql)
```

I tested this code with **Python3.6**, **Django 2.0** and **PostgreSQL 10**.

Comment: If you have more than one database you need `from django.db import connections, router` and then `connection = connections[router.db_for_write(MyModelX)]` for each model to get the right `connection`.

Comment: For me, using SQLite, `sequence_sql` is always empty. It seems that `sequence_reset_sql` by default just returns an empty list and isn't overriden except in PostgreSQL and Oracle. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/sqlsequencereset.py

Comment: This *seems* better than other solutions as you can use models at a certain state of migrations history  (from `apps.get_model()`) where other solutions will use latest model state, which might be inconsistent with the migration.

Answer (score 10):

I'm currently managing this by:

1. Using [call_command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code) to run sqlsequencereset
2. Grabbing the output into an in-memory [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) object (instead of writing to a file on disc)
3. [Executing the SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) against Django's default database

**Code:**

```
import io

from django.core.management import call_command
from django.db import connection


app_name = 'my_app'

# Get SQL commands from sqlsequencereset
output = io.StringIO()
call_command('sqlsequencereset', app_name, stdout=output, no_color=True)
sql = output.getvalue()
    
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql)

output.close()
```

Comment: It should be possible to pass the `--no-color` command line switch to `call_command` and avoid having to manually remove the terminal color codes

Comment: call_command('sqlsequencereset', app_name, stdout=output, no_color=True)

Comment: I've updated/simplified the answer by incorporating @pedrotech 's comment.

Comment: Although this is a correct answer, I generally had a lot of issues whenever I tried to run any management commands like that. Sometimes it is a preferable way to do things but in this particular case it is not. `sqlsequencereset` command contains approximately two lines of actual code (plus some app_configs iteration logic inherited from the `AppCommand` superclass) and it's trivial to copy those lines and get nice lists of sql statements rather than concatenated output steam that has to be parsed and everything.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote Ivan. I didn't claim that the solution was elegant, it was just the quick fix I thought of at the time that I thought may help others.

Comment: NOTE: `StringIO` now is part of io, so for import use `from io import StringIO`

Answer (score 3):

also see `[this gist][1]`, where it can be done e.g. from console for all apps.

```
import os

os.environ['DJANGO_COLORS'] = 'nocolor'

from django.core.management import call_command
from django.db import connection
from django.apps import apps
from io import StringIO

commands = StringIO()
cursor = connection.cursor()

for app in apps.get_app_configs():
    call_command('sqlsequencereset', app.label, stdout=commands)

cursor.execute(commands.getvalue())
```

Comment: This is imo the best answer here.

Comment: Also could just pass `no_color=True` to `call_command()`.

Answer (score 2):

Given that this is an inconsistency in Django's management commands, the best solution may be to see whether it can be fixed at source.  See [Requesting Features](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/bugs-and-features/#requesting-features) for details on how to do this.

Comment: It would be a good idea to ask on django-developement list first, there might've been some reason for implementing it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to use `sequence_reset_sql` if it is supported and to do it via SQL statements otherwise -- a combination of various responses posted so far

```
from django.db import connection
from django.core.management.color import no_style


def resetsequence(appmodels):
    if appmodels is None:
        return

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sequence_sql = connection.ops.sequence_reset_sql(no_style(), appmodels)
        if sequence_sql:
            for sqlstr in sequence_sql:
                cursor.execute(sqlstr)
        else:
            for appmodel in appmodels:
                table = appmodel._meta.db_table
                sqlstr = "ALTER TABLE {:s} AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;".format(table)
                cursor.execute(sqlstr)
```

`appmodels` can be populated automatically via `django.apps.apps.get_app_config()` or manually.